# How to prevent PyCharm from overriding default backend as set in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I've set my default backend to `Qt5Agg` in `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. This works if I use a regular ssh prompt and open `ipython` and run `import matplotlib as mpl`

I correctly get: 
`mpl.get_backend() => "Qt5Agg"`

When I connect through pyCharm remote console, the default backend is set to `'module://backend_interagg'` which seems to be a purpose built helper extension by pycharm.

Using `mpl.use("Qt5Agg")` works as expected (i.e. correctly sets the backend and allows me to use it).

I'm just trying to get the default working and the pycharm remote console to properly use my rc file parameters.

Fwiw, I've tried actually setting my master rc file (in the site-packages directory) to have Qt5Agg and I still get this problem.

Also, `mpl.get_configdir()` correctly returns `~/.config/matplotlib`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem in PyCharm 2017.3.3 and what helped was to disable the checkbox *Show plots in toolwindow* in `File -> Settings -> Tools -> Python Scientific`.

Comment: Amazing. I've looked everywhere and that was one rock I wouldn't have turned over in a million years.

Thank you!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks!
Never forget the old adage - if you change something, you break something.